# I use kubernetes claster and Istio service mesh. Can Spring Cloud Gateway add something to this?

Tags: kubernetes, istio, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm studying `Spring Cloud Gateway` but it seems in case of `kubernetes & Istio` claster stack it's useless, because everything can get from the `kubernetes & Istio` out of the box.

Am I right or I miss something and `Spring Cloud Gateway` can do something they cannot? In other word are there usecases which I cannot solve with `kubernetes & Istio` but rather need `Spring Cloud Gateway`?

Comment: Yes it is. If you have istio installed, spring gateway's basic feature `gateway` is provided by istio. You can customise istio to achieve what spring cloud gateway offers.spring cloud gateway has more functionality in terms of spring eco system. I would suggest not to through it in as long as you don't need it. If you are learning it, please do. It is amazing and might come handy in lot of other occasions. Highly recommended

Comment: do you mean gateway feature is provided by ingress instead of istio?

Comment: Well yes. You can use kubernetes ingress.but istio has it's own concept of gateway and ingress. Istio has awesome documentation on this

Comment: So `kubernetes` has `gateway`, istio has `gateway`. It seems 3rd gateway `spring cloud` is something redundant?